# How to refresh API url till don’t get response

Tags: java, android, api, for-loop, okhttp

What is the best way to keep refresh API GET request till you get response and also gonna use it as background service in java Android

WYT?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  You don't refresh an HTTP request.  Do you mean you want to make continual HTTP requests until you get a response?  That's probably a bad idea.  Or do you mean you want to wait for the http request to finish?  Which makes a lot more sense, but isn't generally what you want to do-  you use multithreading with a callback or observable instead.

Comment: Yes, I want to make continual HTTP requests unit I get desired response if it is a bad idea then what else I can use?

Comment: Why would you think a second request to the same API will get you different results?  Generally it would return the same thing.  If you're waiting for some data to change on the back end, you're better off using some form of push notification.

Comment: So, I’m grabbing some data which can available anytime any second so that’s the reason I’m refreshing it.

Comment: Then you should be using push notifications.  Grabbing it constantly will drain your device's battery, and will also use up their data allowance at a horrific rate.  Not everyone has unlimited, and even if they do they may get throttled after a certain amount.  If this is your backend, it will also cause you to have an INSANE transactions per second rate and overload your servers and databases.  If its a 3rd party API, its a good way to get your app blocked.  Possibly even you sued, because that behavior is indistinguishable from a DOS attack

Comment: Could you please elaborate how can I use push notifications with it?